# roots of sum of two polynomials

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

I believe that there is no common theory for finding roots of polynomial sum. In my case I have 
$$P_{n}(x)+AQ_{n}(x)$$.
I am wondering how roots of this sum depend on $A$?

Comment: What is assumed about $P_n$, $Q_n$ and their roots?

Comment: Highly non-trivial techniques to do this were developed by Goldstein and Schlag in http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~schlag/papers/gaps.pdf and http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~schlag/papers/equi.pdf . They had quite a specific problem in mind, so this might not be too helpful for you. The buzzword there is "Jensen formula".

Comment: in my case $P_n$ and $Q_n$ are known rekursiv  polynomials of degree $n$.Positive.A>0. So all roots are complex

Comment: would $P_n(x) + AxP_n(x)$ makes the problem simpler ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If they are complex polynomials or can be treated as such, then you could apply [Rouche's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem), where the location of the zeros is determined by the dominant polynomial within the sum. (*"Walk the dog on the leash"*)

Possibly related: you could use the [Wronskian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian) to determine the values of A that make $P_n(x)$ and $Q_n(x)$ linearly independent.

Your question is related to [Mason's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MasonsTheorem.html).  There are a few papers which explore this specifically

1. *MR1923392 (2003j:30012)  Kim, Seon-Hong . Factorization of sums of
   polynomials.  Acta Appl. Math.  73 
   (2002),  no. 3, 275--284.*
2. *MR2103113 (2005h:30011)  Kim,
   Seon-Hong . On zeros of certain sums
   of polynomials.  Bull. Korean Math.
   Soc.  41  (2004),  no. 4, 641--646*
3. *MR1911767 (2003d:11036)  Pintér, Á. 
   Zeros of the sum of polynomials.  J.
   Math. Anal. Appl.  270  (2002),  no.
   1, 303--305.*

Answer (score 8):

Though in general you won't have a closed-form expression for the roots of your polynomials, it's possible to write down perturbation series for roots of a polynomial in a single variable in terms of the coefficients.  These are basically the Puiseux series mentioned in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15528/asymptotic-series-for-roots-of-polynomials).

[This paper by Bernd Sturmfels](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.44.6531&rep=rep1&type=pdf) ([MR](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1731613)) sketches out the "global picture" of such series, though it's fairly complicated and I personally am not clear on whether there's a simple algorithm to decide which is the proper choice of series that will converge.  See also the article "Algebraic equations and hypergeometric series" by M Passare, A Tsikh in the book: *The Legacy of Niels Henrik Abel* ([MR](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2077589)).

What I've just written is probably a little unclear so I'll describe the simplest example.  Suppose you'd like to write down a series for the roots of $a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0=0$.  There are a pair of series which converges when $\left|\frac{a_1^2}{4a_0a_2}\right|<1$ and a pair which converges when $\left|\frac{a_1^2}{4a_0a_2}\right|>1$, and you can derive the first pair of series by treating $a_1x$ as a perturbation to the equation $a_2x^2+a_0=0$ and you can derive one of the second pair of series by treating $a_2x^2$ as a perturbation to $a_1x+a_0=0$ and the other by treating $a_0$ as a perturbation to the equation $a_2x^2+a_1x=0$.

By plugging in the coefficients of $P_n(x)+AQ_n(x)$ into the appropriate series I just described and looking at the leading order terms as functions of $A$, you will be able to derive the scaling of the corrections to the roots of $P_n(x)$.

Apologies for the rather unexplicit answer, but this is just at the limit of what I understand.