# Near Pochhammer symbols: the equation $(n)_m-(k)_l=2$ for integers greater than or equal to two

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, factorization, divisors-multiples

In this post I consider the following equation involving Pochhammer symbols,

$$(n)_m-(k)_l=2\tag{1}$$

for positive integers $n\geq 2$ and $k\geq 2$, and positive integers $m\geq 2$ and $l\geq 2$.

See if you need the definition of a Pochhammer symol from the artice *Pochhammer Symbol* of the encyclopedia Wolfram MathWorld.

We denote the solutions as $(n,m;k,l)$, but feel free to use a different notation if improve mine.

**Example.** One has the $(n,m;k,l)=(22,2;7,3)$ is a solution of our equation since $$(22)_2-(7)_3=\frac{(22+2-1)!}{(22-1)!}-\frac{(7+3-1!)}{(7-1)!}=23\cdot22-9\cdot8\cdot7=2.$$

**Computations.** I can to find two solutions of $(1)$ satisfying previous requirements for the integers $n,m,k$ and $l$ greater than or equal to $2$, these are $(n,m;k,l)=(22,2;7,3)$ and $(n,m;k,l)=(31,2;9,3)$. Below I add a code written in Pari/GP.

> **Question.** Is it possible to deduce that the equation 
>   $$(n)_m-(k)_l=2$$
>   has finitely many solutions for integers $n,m,k,l\geq 2$? **Many thanks.**

I hope that my proposal of problem is interesting. I don't know if there is other problem more interesting than my Question, I was also tempted to ask about what can be a similar problem involving ratios of Pochammer symbols, but I didn't experiments in this case.

**Details for the computational evidence.** My code was written in Pari/GP. Search in Internet, *Sage Cell Server* and paste next code choosing as Language *GP*. I say this line

`for(n=2, 50, for(m=2,50,for(k=2,50, for(l=2,50, if((n+m-1)!/(n-1)!-(k+l-1)!/(k-1)!==2,print(n))))))`

Comment: First, at least one of $m,l$ must be greater than 2. Then, it follows that $m=2$ since otherwise the equation has no solutions modulo $3$.

Comment: For the case $m=2,l=3,$ when we know $m\approx (n(n-1))^{1/3},$ some Magma computation on the online magma calculator has yielded the following solutions (checked up to $n\leq 10^6$): $(n,m)\in \{(23,9),(32,11),(18959,712)\}.$

Comment: Many thanks for both valueable remarks in previous comments. Also, if some user is interested in studying other types of equations involving Pochhammer symbols, that these users feel free to do it.

Comment: @kodlu: These are all solution for $(m,l)=(2,3)$. In this case, the equation defines an elliptic curve $n^2+n = k^3+3k^2+2k+2$, where all integral points can be computed, e.g., in sage:
**EllipticCurve([0,3,1,2,2]).integral_points()** gives **[(-2 : 1 : 1),  (-1 : 1 : 1),  (0 : 1 : 1),  (7 : 22 : 1),  (9 : 31 : 1),  (710 : 18958 : 1)]**

Comment: For $(m,l)=(2,4)$, we have a hyperelliptic curve: $(2n+1)^2 = 4k^4 + 24k^3 + 44k^2 + 24k + 9$, for which we can use Magma to find its integral points: **IntegralQuarticPoints([4,24,44,24,9]);** gives **[ [ -3, -3 ], [ -2, 3 ], [ -1, 3 ], [ 0, 3 ] ]**, i.e., there are no solutions with $n,k\geq 2$.

Comment: Many thanks I am following and run your codes in Sage Cell Server @MaxAlekseyev , as soon you want you and your colleague in previous comments can add your results as an answer: it can to draw more attention of other professors.

Comment: The case $(2,4)$, or more generally each case $(2,l)$ for  *even* $l$,
is elementary, because it comes down to finding square values of
a polynomial that is not identically a square but has
square leading coefficient, and is thus amenable to the method
I described in
<https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66873/how-to-decide-this-function-takes-integer-values/67202#67202>.

Comment: Many thanks @NoamD.Elkies for the analysis of the cases, and the linked post.

Comment: I believe that you may be interested in my recent paper {\it On the Diophantine equation $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{m}{l}+d$}, J NUMBER THEORY vol. 208 (2020), 418-440 (joint with H. R. Gallegos-Ruiz, N. Katspis and Sz. Tengely), where the problem of near binomial coefficients is investigated.

Comment: Many thanks for such good reference @MaciejUlas , now I can not upvote your comment (due my low reputation) but I appreciate it. You or your colleagues feel free to explore my question/s.