# Can $y^2-4$ be a divisor of $x^3-x^2-2 x+1$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Do there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that $\frac{x^3-x^2-2 x+1}{y^2-4}$ is an integer?

In other words, can any integer representable as $x^3-x^2-2 x+1$ have any divisor representable as $y^2-4$?

This is the simplest non-trivial example of my earlier question [Integer points of rational function in 2 variables](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/404703/integer-points-of-rational-function-in-2-variables) .

Comment: This is the simplest non-trivial example of my earlier question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/404703/integer-points-of-rational-function-in-2-variables . I have added this to the question.

Comment: I am sorry, can you please explain why the prime divisor $q$ of $p_a(n)$ must be congruent to a cubic residue modulo $P$? I looked at Shank's paper and this is stated without detailed proof, with just one intermediate step that $q^{(P-1)/3}$ is $1$ mod $P$, which I also do not know why. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No.  The roots of $x^3 - x^2 - 2x + 1$ are $-(\zeta + \zeta^{-1})$ where $\zeta$ is a 7th root of unity; this soon implies [*see below*] that any prime factor is either $7$ or $\pm 1 \bmod 7$, and thus that all factors of $x^3 - x^2 - 2x + 1$ are congruent to $0$ or $\pm 1 \bmod 7$.  In particular it is not possible for two factors to differ by $4$, so no number of the form $y^2 - 4 = (y-2) (y+2)$ can divide $x^3 - x^2 - 2x + 1$.

*added later*: To show that any prime factor $p$ of $x^3 - x^2 - 2x + 1$ is either $7$ or $\pm 1 \bmod 7$, let $k$ be the finite field of order $p^2$, and $\zeta \in k$ a root of the quadratic equation $\zeta^2 + x\zeta + 1 = 0$ (any quadratic equation with coefficients in the $p$-element field has a root in $k$).  Then $\zeta^7 = 1$, so either $\zeta = 1$ or the multiplicative group $k^\times$ of $k$ has a subgroup of size $7$.  In the former case, $x = -2$, and then $x^3 - x^2 - 2x + 1 = -7$ so $p=7$.  In the latter case, [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)#Applications) gives $7 \mid \#k^\times = p^2-1$, so $p \equiv \pm 1 \bmod 7$.  **QED**